# How to find if a string contains all the certain characters?

Tags: python, regex

For example:

```
Characters to match: 'czk'
string1: 'zack' Matches
string2: 'zak'  Does not match
```

I tried `(c)+(k)+(z)` and `[ckz]` which are obviously wrong. I feel this is a simple task, but i am unable to find an answer

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? `all(x in string for x in 'czk')`

Comment: Without regex you could: `set('czk').issubset(your_string)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural way would probably to use sets rather than regex, like so

```
set('czk').issubset(s)
```

Code is very often simpler and easier to maintain without using regex much.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to sort the string first so you get "ackz" and then you can use a regex like `/.*c.*k.*z.*/` to match against.

Comment: new [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) library supports "fuzzy" matching directly: `/(?:ckz){i}/`.